# Count frequencies of pairs in matrix matlab

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

I have matrix X , mX2, I want to result a matrix S of size

```
size(unique(X(:,2),1) X size(unique(X(:,2),1)
```

for each S(i,j) I want to count how many times i,j appeared together.
for example:

```
X = [1 11 ; 
     2 11; 
     3 11; 
     5 23; 
     6 23;
     1 23; 
     9 24;
     9 25;
     3 23;
    10 23]
unique(X(:,2)) 
11
23
24
25
```

S should be:

```
 0     2     0     0
 0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     1
 0     0     0     0
```

(I don't care about diagonals, and it could either have them or not, also,S could be symmetric).

```
S(1,2) = 2
```

because 11 and 23 (which are in position 1,2) appeared together twice (i.e with the same value in X(:,1)).

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one way of doing it:

```
[~, ~, n1] = unique(X(:,1));
[~, ~, n2] = unique(X(:,2));
B = accumarray([n2 n1],1);
S = B*B';
```

This gives the full matrix:

```
>> S
S =
     3     2     0     0
     2     5     0     0
     0     0     1     1
     0     0     1     1
```

To remove the diagonal and lower triangle you can use

```
S = triu(B*B',1);
```

which yields

```
>> S
S =
     0     2     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1
     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: +1 nice trick with the matrix multiplication, not directly obvious how it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
% convert each columns to indices starting from 1
[a,~,aa] = unique(X(:,1));
[b,~,bb] = unique(X(:,2));

% group occurences of col2 according to values of col1
C = accumarray(aa, bb, [], @(x){x});

% keep only occurences of two or more values
C = C(cellfun(@numel,C) > 1);

% in case of three or more values co-occured, generate all pairs
C = cellfun(@(v) nchoosek(v,2), C, 'UniformOutput',false);

% concatenate all pairs
C = cell2mat(C);

% build count matrix
C = sparse(C(:,[1 2]), C(:,[2 1]), 1);
C = full(C);
```

The result in this case (obviously a symmetric matrix):

```
>> C
C =
     0     2     0     0
     2     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1
     0     0     1     0
```

or pretty-printed with row/column headers:

```
>> [{[]} num2cell(b'); num2cell(b) num2cell(C)]
ans = 
      []    [11]    [23]    [24]    [25]
    [11]    [ 0]    [ 2]    [ 0]    [ 0]
    [23]    [ 2]    [ 0]    [ 0]    [ 0]
    [24]    [ 0]    [ 0]    [ 0]    [ 1]
    [25]    [ 0]    [ 0]    [ 1]    [ 0]
```

Comment: very nice, but a bit of an overkill after [Mohsen's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18712356/1714410).